# Azure MySQL in-app: Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: mysql, php, azure

I'm running an app-service on Azure with a PHP application and a MySQL in-app database on it. This app service has a lot of small requests coming in (i.e. to get or update a leaderboard for a game).

Often, I see the following warning coming by in the log file of the PHP application:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

I receive several complaints from players that they fail to update their score on the leaderboards, which I connect to seeing this warning a lot in the logs. I traced the issue being that connections are being held in the TIME_WAIT state for too long on the level of the operating system, or that the range of ports that can be used is simply too small to handle more connections.

How can I adjust this on Azure so that this warning is either gone, or a lot less frequent? I use the `close()` function on my mysqli objects to clear the connection, but as I understand correctly, this doesn't immediately release the underlying resources in the OS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way TCP/IP connections close:

- You ask to close the connection (`FIN`),
- The server acknowledges it received your request (`ACK`) and also asks to close its side (`FIN`),
- You acknowledge (`ACK`) that and wait around **4 minutes** (`TIME_WAIT` state) to be sure that no packets sent by the server and delayed by the network will arrive. During this time you can not use the same port to connect to the server.

**mysqli** probably uses several source ports, but even if it used all of them, the limit is around 270 connections per second.

To solve your problem, enable [persistent connections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.allow-persistent) in PHP and don't close them. An old connection will be reused whenever possible.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know that existed, and would never have started to look for anything like this. Persistent connections seem to be on by default (as I haven't changed the value) and php info says they are enabled. So if I understand correctly, I only need to **not** close the connections in order for them to remain available?

Comment: Yes, if you don't close them, they remain open for the next script execution. I am assuming you are not using the old CGI interface, which ends the PHP interpreter after every execution.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean with 'old cgi interface'. Any way for me to quickly check that? Some quick googling didn't come up with something useful. I am using the PHP mysqli extension, if that's any relevant information.

Comment: By old CGI interface I mean **mod_cgi** in Apache or similar: this plugin starts a separate PHP interpreter for every request, so the connections will be closed after each request anyway. You most probably use **mod_php** or **FPM-PHP**. You can test that everything works by sending thousands of requests per second to your server.

Comment: When I run the `php_sapi_name()` function, it returns the value 'cgi-fcgi'. This seems like it's not running as an Apache module, and neither being the old interface. So I will setup the changes on the test server and see if I can flood it with some requests.

Comment: It seems the persistent connections are working. I've been sending out multiple requests per second for a few minutes. The non-persistent code fails within a minute while the persistent one is still going. Thank you!